# Publicly expose a directory on Pantheon (Drupal 7)

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7, pantheon

I have a D7 site on Pantheon with a dir in sites/default/files that I want to make publicly accessible and navigable (you should be able to navigate the folder structure and files from within a web browser - no styling necessary).

I've tried creating a module that displays the contents of the dir on a dynamically created page (using hook_menu) and it works on local but on Pantheon it's blocked (with a generic not found Pantheon error).

Any help is greatly appreciated!